# jest@28 babel-jest config file path

Tags: typescript, jestjs, config, babel-jest

I bumped `jest` from version 27 to 28 in a monorepo and figured jest@28 don't pick up the babel config anymore. I read about the breaking changes in the [migration guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28) especially the section about the [babel config changes](https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28#babel-config) but I am a bit confused by what this exactly means:

> babel-jest now passes root: config.rootDir to Babel when resolving
> configuration. This improves compatibility when using projects with
> differing configuration, but it might mean your babel config isn't
> picked up in the same way anymore.

This is how my project is structured:

- It's a standard monorepo that relies on lerna and yarn classic workspaces.
- `jest` is installed as a workspace de dependency
- babel dependencies are also installed as workspace dependencies
- tests are written in TypeScript and transpile through `babel-jest`

Babel config file (`babel.config.js`) lives at the root of the repo, and only configures jest to transpile TypeScript tests:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
        '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ]
}
```

Jest as a root config (`root.config.js`) that's passed to the npm script:

```
module.exports = {
    rootDir: '../..',
    projects: [
        '<rootDir>/packages/@scope/packageA',
        '<rootDir>/packages/@scope/packageB',
        '<rootDir>/packages/@scope/packageC',

    ],

    // Global mono-repo code coverage threshold.
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 80,
            functions: 85,
            lines: 85,
        },
    },

};
```

And also has a common config (`common.config.js` that's imported and extended in every project:

```
module.exports = {
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.spec.ts'],
};
```

I had to update the `common.config.js` jest config with the following to make it work with jest 28:

```
module.exports = {
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.spec.ts'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.[jt]sx?$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: './babel.config.js' }],
    },
};
```

Note that the jest root and common config files are under `<wkspceRoot>/scripts/jest`.

I am just wondering if there's a way to ensure that `babel-jest` pick up my babel config file without having to explicitly pass it in and what the quoted change means in detail.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and tried renaming `babel.config.js`to `.babelrc` and jest took notice of this babel config. I'm still confused about this effect as it doesn't make any sense to me.